# Como Desativar cache em links específicos via htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, htaccess, apache, cache

Após pesquisar bastante sobre o assunto, vou reformular minha pergunta.

Vai ficar mais claro:

Em meu site **Wordpress**, eu gostaria de definir a expiração dos arquivos  html **apenas** na página inicial do site "**homepage**" para que o **browser** não salve o cache.

Eu tentei usando o código abaixo para definir a expiração de todos os html para **1 semana**, e da **homepage** "index.html" **para 0**.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 week"
    <FilesMatch "^(index\.html)$">
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Mas apenas a configuração de 1 semana funcionou.

```
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 week"
```

A configuração dentro de "FilesMatch" é completamente ignorada.

```
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
```

Porém, quando eu tento definir a expiração do arquivo **styles.css** no lugar de index.html, usando a mesma estrutura, o código funciona.

Logo, parece que algo relacionado ao fato de definir a expiração especificamente do arquivo index.html dentro de "**FilesMatch**" impede o código de funcionar.

Eu sei que o wordpress não possui um arquivo **index.html**, ele possui um **index.php** que gera o html. mas provavelmente o nome do arquivo html usado na página home do wordpress não é index. deve ser outra coisa.

Então a pergunta é, **como definir a expiração do arquivo html somente na página home**?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que o propósito e o funcionamento de caches não está muito claro para você. O objetivo de se usar cache é para evitar processamentos mais "pesados" e com baixa probabilidade de serem necessários. Deve-se criar mecanismos de cache para processamentos repetitivos e sem alterações durante a existência do cache.

Um exemplo seria uma homepage de um site com muitas visitas. Todos os visitantes devem ver o mesmo conteúdo logo, não é necessário fazer consultas à base de dados para cada visita, por exemplo. Neste caso, pode-se "montar" o html da página uma única vez e utilizá-lo para todos os visitantes.

Uma forma simples e comum de se ter cache em páginas web é com headers específicos que indicam ao navegador do usuário se ele deve aproveitar o conteúdo que já tem armazenado localmente ou se deve fazer uma requisição ao servidor. O header mais comum para isso é o `cache-control` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control).

Dependendo de como estiver o header `cache-control`, em um pedido subsequente de um mesmo usuário, o navegador do próprio usuário vai verificar se já tem o conteúdo localmente e se o mesmo está dentro das regras de expiração definidas. Caso positivo, *não* é sequer feito um request ao servidor.

Em adição ao header `cache-control`, pode-se usar o `ETag`. O objetivo deste é que o navegador identifique se uma URL teve o seu conteúdo alterado *depois* da expiração do cache.

Pelo que foi descrito, não parece ser o que você precisa. O mais provável é que vc esteja procurando algum cache no servidor para evitar que *diferentes* utilizadores façam requests que demandem recursos do seu servidor. Para isso, deve-se buscar outras formas de cache, como armazenar o html final gerado pelo seu site. Existem inúmeros plugins de Wordpress que fazem todo este controle automaticamente (e inclusive vão configurar os headers adequadamente para a maioria dos tipos de arquivos como scripts, css e imagens).

---

Respondendo mais diretamente as perguntas:

1. Pode fazer algo como

```
<FilesMatch "<URL>">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

2. Não há como fazer isso com o Apache/configuração no .htaccess, tão pouco faz sentido a pergunta. O que, de certa forma pode ser feito é `caso o cache tenha expirado` verificar se há mudanças no conteúdo (para isso pode ser usado o `ETag`).
3. Tente antes ler sobre diferentes tipos de caching e onde usá-los. Mas se procura a documentação do .htaccess do Apache, aqui vai: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html.

Comment: O wordpress salva cache da busca. se não recarregar a página após cada busca, continuará vendo resultados desatualizados.

Preciso desabilitar o cache somente nesta URL de busca.
O código que consegui criar gera um erro 500.

Comment: Veja o meu htaccess:

# ALL - 1 YEAR CACHE
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

# SEARCH RESULTS - 1 SECOND CACHE
<LocationMatch ".*/\?s=.*">
  <ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 second"
  </ifModule>
</LocationMatch>

Comment: De que cache vc está falando @lgdelai? E para que fazer cache de 1s? Se for uma página com milhares de acessos por segundo até faria sentido, mas ainda assim não seria nas pesquisas.

Comment: E de onde veio "O wordpress salva cache da busca. se não recarregar a página após cada busca, continuará vendo resultados desatualizados."?

Comment: Olá @tvdias, obrigado pela sua ajuda até aqui, eu pesquisei bastante a respeito, e reformulei minha pergunta, acho que agora ficará bem mais claro o que eu desejo. Se puder dê uma olhada, agradeço.